# How do I use the ion-menu and ion-slides on the same page?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I use to Ionic5. Implementation of ion-slides in ion-menu not working.`İon-Slider` comes in the `ion-menu`. I did the ion-menu. Pressing the menu button will open the menu. The ion-slider appears in the menu. And there must be an ion-slider at the entrance.

home.html code :

```
  <ion-header>
      <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title>Anasayfa</ion-title>
            <ion-buttons slot="start">
           <ion-menu-button autoHide="false">
           </ion-menu-button>
        </ion-buttons>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
    <ion-app>
        <ion-menu contentId="content1" side="start">
            <ion-header>
                <ion-toolbar>
                    <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
                </ion-toolbar>
            </ion-header>
        <ion-content>
     <ion-list>
     <ion-item routerLink="/etk">
       <ion-icon name="calendar" slot="start"></ion-icon>
          <ion-label>Etkinlikler</ion-label>
     </ion-item>

         <ion-item routerLink="/ilan">
              <ion-icon name="business" slot="start"></ion-icon>
                  <ion-label>İş İlanları</ion-label>
           </ion-item> 
      <ion-item routerLink="/sce">
         <ion-icon name="help" slot="start"></ion-icon>
             <ion-label>Soru-Cevap</ion-label>
        </ion-item>

            <ion-item>
               <ion-icon name="log-out" slot="start"></ion-icon>
                   <ion-label>Çıkış Yap</ion-label>
                        <ion-button routerLink="/login" routerDirection="root"></ion-button>
            </ion-item>


                    </ion-list>

    <ion-slides>
        <ion-slide>
            <h1>Slide 5</h1>
        </ion-slide>

    </ion-slides>
        </ion-content>
            </ion-menu>
        <ion-router-outlet id="content1" main></ion-router-outlet>

    </ion-app>
```

Comment: i don't see any issue in your code. it should work fine. Can you make stackblitz

Comment: By `Ionic5` you mean the CLI version.. You need to clarify your ionic _framework_ version.